# Error "Unable to run 'docker-compose' " when loading docker enabled project on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I got this message when adding docker-compose support for a visual studio project:

[image]

About the environment:

I have docker installed and running. I was able to run the docker hello-world test app.
I am using visual studio 2019 on a windows 2019 server. Not a typical developer environment.

It is my first docker project, so i may have failed to understand some basics.

Comment: Open a command-prompt and type `where docker-compose` and see what it says.

Comment: it runs, but meanwhile i had installed dockerforwindows. Also vs can now run and debug, but i think there should be a less messy solution. The dockerforwindows setup may have installed docker-compose, but also installed the destop utility that fails to start on this windows 2019. Also, docker was already running.